# Creating ggplot with segregated columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data which looks like this:

[image: Data picture]

And here is my code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(Month.of.Death, fill=as.factor(Month.of.Death)))+
  geom_bar(color="black",fill="brown3")+
  theme(text = element_text(size=15),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))+
  labs(title = "Liczba śmierci dziennikarzy w danym miesiącu", x="Miesiąc", y="Liczba dziennikarzy")
```

[image: How chart looks like]

So now what is my problem. I was trying to make put these columns in order but I do not know how to do it. I have been trying to do it using this:

```
miesiac <- c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "Novermber", "December")
```

but when I try to add it as my new X axis it says it has different amount of elements then Y. I do understand the problem but I am unable to find solution I saw people in internet doing it this way but either I am stupid or it does not work for my problem. Please tell me how to sort these columns.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have a specific order you need (in this case, the order of months), you should make that variable a factor. Otherwise ggplot will order alphabetically. Your chart shows 13 categories, but the axis labels you gave have 12, and only 11 match what's in the data: "unknown" is missing and November is misspelled. Beyond that, there are lots of SO posts on ordering axis labels already; we'd need to have a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to know how this isn't covered by any of those

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/20524408/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/30217594/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/12774210/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/35559058/5325862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to add `scale_x_discrete` functions and pass the ordering in the argument `limits`:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(Month.of.Death, fill=Month.of.Death))+
  geom_bar(color="black",fill="brown3")+
  theme(text = element_text(size=15),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))+
  labs(title = "Liczba śmierci dziennikarzy w danym miesiącu", x="Miesiąc", y="Liczba dziennikarzy")+
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December","Unknown"))
```

If this is not working, please consider to add a reproducible example of your dataset as specified here: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)